# Why isn't the denominator in bayes rule always one

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem, monty-hall

So, I thought I kind of understood Bayes and total probability, but I see now I am not clear on the calculation and which information to take in. I read an article that was using the Monty Hall problem, and it said that the proof was as follows:

Consider you chose door 1 and Monty opens door 3, which has a goat behind. Now, say A is the event that door 1 has a car behind and B that door 3 had a goat behind. So, in Bayes terms:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)p(A^c)}$$

My problem comes with the denominator. In the article they calulculate it as $\frac{1\times \frac{1}{3}}{1\times 1/3+1\times \frac{1}{3}}$That means he already uses the information that, because B is given, then all probabilites of the form P(B|__)  are equal to 1. My doubt is that, if I can do this, then all calculations in total probability would be trivially one (we would have $P(\Omega )$.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: $P(B|A^c)=0$ since $B$ cannot have the goat behind it if given that $A$ has the goat behind it.

Comment: I think the denominator should be $1\times \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{3}$. If $A$ is true (probability $1/3$) $B$ must be true (i.e., $P(B|A)=1$), since there can only be a car. If $A$ is false (probability $1-1/3=2/3$), then in the third door we can have either a goat (the one is left) or a car, so $P(B|A^c)=1/2$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField totally right. Thanks.

Comment: @dvdgrgrtt Almost follow you, but when you say that $P(B|A^c)=\frac{1}{2}$ because there is only two possibilites I get confused. Aren't you saying that two outcomes implies equal probability 1/2?

Comment: Yes, given that one goat is behind door 1 (we are assuming $A^c$), we have two possible outcomes: the car behind door 2 and the other goat behind door 3 or vice versa. Out of the two, we are only interested in one (event B, i.e. goat behind door 3), so the probability is $P(B|A^c)=1/2$.